# Can't install PostgreSQL: An error occurred executing the Microsoft VC++ runtime installer on Windows XP

Tags: postgresql, windows-xp

I downloaded installer postgresql-9.0.1-1-windows.exe from the official site, ran it, and then got an error:

> An error occurred executing the Microsoft VC++ runtime installer

What is the reason for this error message?

Platform: Windows XP SP3, Dell Inspiron 1501. Processor: AMD Sempron 3500+

Comment: @bernie https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Running_%26_Installing_PostgreSQL_On_Native_Windows

Answer (score 277, accepted):

One of the reasons this can happen is because the installer attempts to install an older version of the VC++ runtime than what you are currently using.

See this installation log, found in your user's temporary directory (e.g. `dd_vcredist_amd64_20190214193107.log`):

> [20C0:20E4][2019-02-14T19:31:07]e000: Error 0x80070666: Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed.

[A workaround](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2010-10/msg00107.php) is to prevent the runtimes from installing with the `--install_runtimes` option:

```
postgresql-9.6.12-1-windows-x64.exe --install_runtimes 0
```

Comment: Gives me `There has been an error. Error running XXX\getlocales.exe : Program ended with an err or exit code` on 9.6 and 10.6.

Comment: 2019 and I encountered the same issue installing version postgresql-11.1-1-windows-x64.exe. Launching it with --install_runtimes 0 definitely solved the problem.

Answer (score 76):

1. Create a shortcut of the downloaded file:

   [image]
2. Right click of the shortcut → *Properties* → *Shortcut*. Add **--install_runtimes 0** to the end of the file path:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you! This solves it for me, I have every VC++ runtime from 08-17 installed and yet this install kept failing.

Comment: Thanks for this brilliant solution!

Comment: Worked perfectly for win 10

Answer (score 16):

- Create a shortcut of your EXE file;
- right click on the shortcut → add `--install_runtimes 0` at the end of the target path, e.g.:

  ```
  postgresql-9.3.1-1-windows-x64.exe --install_runtimes 0
  ```
- save and run it :)

Answer (score 4):

First download and install Microsoft Visual C++ from the Microsoft website. Then run the installation from command with `--install_runtimes 0`.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue and found a fix that worked for me from Garrett_H in this forum post:

http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/1747.page#6180

> Go to file %windir%\inf\wsh.inf, right click and select 'Install'
>
> re-run postgresql installer

I'm running Windows XP Pro, and I was trying to install `postgresql-8.3.17-1-windows.exe`. I originally received the following error:

> An error occurred executing the Microsoft C++ runtime installer.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken (it redirects to a generic place).

Comment: Looks like that forum is long gone. Best I could find was this wayback machine link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160427090126/http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/1747.page

Answer (score 3):

In my case, when I was installing `postgresql-11.0-1-windows-x64.exe` on Windows 10, I had faced the same problem.

I just uninstalled the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (the latest one for both 32 and 64 bit) and then tried to install `postgresql-11.0-1-windows-x64.exe` again, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing as administrator (using *Run as administrator*).

In version 9.0. PostgreSQL can be installed as a Windows administrator :)

Answer (score 2):

Check if [Windows Script Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) (WSH) is enabled. If not enabled, details are here: *[PostgreSQL Installation Problem on Windows without WSH](http://1stopit.blogspot.com/2011/01/postgresql-83-and-84-fails-to-install.html)*

Answer (score 2):

Take special care that your Windows user's folder name does not contain spaces. PostgreSQL (as of version 9.2.2.1) handles that poorly. If I use this account on Windows XP, installation fails with the "An error occurred executing the Microsoft C++ runtime installer" message:

```
"C:\Documents and settings\Jimmy (admin)"
```

But it runs just fine with this:

```
"C:\Documents and settings\Jimmy-admin"
```

The spaces in "Documents and settings" don't seem to bother the installer. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

Go to file `%windir%\inf\wsh.inf`, right click, and select 'Install'.

Then re-run the PostgreSQL installer.

This works on Windows XP with PostgreSQL 8.4.17-1.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same issue. I fixed it in the following way:

1. I visited the below site:
   https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads
2. Choose the Download button under PostgreSQL Version 11.1  for Windows x86-64.

In one word, just try to install the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Script Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) (WSH) is unable to execute VBScript scripts. This can occur if the scripting host is disabled (which is unusual), or if the installation is broken. A sign of this problem is a message like

> CScript Error: Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script "C:....

It can often be resolved by re-registering the VBScript interpreter, click Start * → * *Run* and enter the following and click <kbd>OK</kbd>:

```
regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\vbscript.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to install PostgreSQL version 11.1. I had to uninstall the Microsoft VC++ and run the installer again. It downloaded the required VC++ and the installation went successful.

Answer (score 0):

I had these same problems and tried

- manually installing MS VC++
- bypassing VC++ installation on postgres
- fixing windows update service

Still unsuccessful

Then I solved these problem by installing postgres manually:

- extract the PostgreSQL installation contents to C:\PostgreSQL (you can copy from successful installation on other machines)
- add C:\PostgreSQL\bin to PATH environment
- run `pg_ctl register -D D:\pgdata -N postgresql -U postgres -P <your postgres password>`