# Postgresql: Error running c:\\...getlocales.exe : child killed: unknown signal

Tags: sql, postgresql, enterprisedb

I tried installing PostgreSQL v14.2, 14.1, 11.1  from EnterpriseDB, but I keep getting the following error after the splash screen

Here's the error popup:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOBRO.png)

Here's the error message:

> There has been an error. Error running c:\people\my
> sys\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_13452d4258\getlocales.exe
> : child killed: unknown signal

Any help as to what I can do to fix this and install PostgreSQL.

Ps: I have tried installing several VC++ packages, disabled anti-virus still no way out??

Comment: PostgreSQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to posting questions here. Did you mean I should remove the 'SQL server' from my tags? I think @Aaron have done that.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after adding "--install_runtimes 0" to my commandline install (as recommended by answers to [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288303/cant-install-postgresql-an-error-occurred-executing-the-microsoft-vc-runtime)

Doing a normal, non-commandline install worked properly and then let all future commandline installs work too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case installing postgres 13 in windows 7 64 bits...

If you go and run locales.exe you will see another error message that "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-11-1-0.dll" is missing.

This dll is added by installing the windows update KB2999226, windows update service must be running or you will get other error.

After this it will install correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install [MSVC Redistributable](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)